# How can I implement .ovpn file via flutter_openvpn package in flutter

Tags: flutter, openvpn

I wanna create a VPN application with flutter and I'm gonna do it with the `.ovpn` file.

I found this cool [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_openvpn) on [pub.dev](http://pub.dev) but I can't understand neither the documentation nor the sample code.
I imported the `.ovpn` file in my assets and now I'm clueless about what should I do.

I would be happy to receive help from senior developers here.

Thanks

Comment: did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `assets/vpnconfig.ovp` into assets folder and then read the using the file content using `rootBundle.loadString`

```
var contennt=await rootBundle.loadString('assets/vpnconfig.ovpn');
await FlutterOpenvpn.lunchVpn(
  contennt,
      ....
  
);
```